# How do I change the webconsole port when running the QuestDB binary?

Tags: questdb

I'm running the QuestDB Java binary using the `questdb.sh` script, but I don't see any way to change the web console port from 9000 to something else.

Is there a way to serve on port 80 without doing any nginx proxy shenanigans?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the **http.bind.to** property in the **server.conf** file. It defaults to **0.0.0.0:9000**, if you change it to **127.0.0.1:80** and restart the server then the web console will be served from http://localhost/.

You can visit the [configuration documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration) page for more information on all the properties in the **server.conf** file.